# Run-Length Encoding assumptions

Tags: c#, compression, run-length-encoding

When implementing the [Run-length encoding (RLE)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Run-length_encoding), can I assume that the *Runs* are going to be shorter than one byte?

So there will not be a situation where there is a run like this

```
WWWBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBBB...
```

Where there are 256 B's because you cannot represent that length in one byte whereas you can represent the W's as 3W

If not, should the *Run* be split into two *Runs*? How should this situation be handled? I couldn't find any information about this case.

Comment: I don't understand what you mean by assuming that a run would be shorter than one byte, but whatever it means, it would depend on your implementation of RLE. RLE is a type of compression with many ways to implement it.

Comment: Yeah this is not very clear. I mean, you ask a question, then in the case of no you ask a completely different unrelated question, please be more specific

Comment: Much more clear after the edit, and as I predicted, it totally depends on how you choose to implement it. However, if you limit the length value to one byte, then of course a run can only be the number of distinct lengths that can be described by a byte. You could also use some form of variable-length length encoding to enable longer runs. In any case, a run longer than the capability of your length encoding will need to be split,

Comment: @glenebob you should write this up as an answer!

Comment: It depends... the most classic code/token based RLE algorithms I've seen actually uses that single byte for both indicating whether it's a 'copy following data' or a 'repeat single value' command, and to indicate a length, meaning you got a 1-bit command + 7 bits of length in there, meaning the maximum run length to store in one command is only 127 then.

Answer (score 1):

To my understanding, you understand the situation correctly. The word length used for counting the repetition of a character is usually a byte, and the individual characters usually are also encoded as a byte. If in the input there is a repetition of e.g. 300 `b`, the encoding will be as follows.

```
255 (number of repetitions of the next character)
 98 (ASCII value for b)
 45 (nunber of repetitions of the next character)
 98 (ASCII value for b)
```

In total, a run of length larger than 255 will have to be split in two runs. That being said, the actual encoding depends on the specific implementations; it is also possible to use other types than bytes for counting the repetition of characters.

Comment: Unfortunately, naïve pair-RLE like that will quickly run into [the "abracadabra" problem](http://www.shikadi.net/moddingwiki/RLE_Compression); uncompressable data will immediately double in size.